# What is the plant tag used for?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed today that there is the tag: [plant](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plant).

There's currently no tag wiki for it, and from the questions that use the tag I'm not really sure what the tag is supposed to be used for.

I would kind of assume that any question would be about a plant, unless it was otherwise stated, so maybe we don't even need the tag at all?

What's up with [plant](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plant)?

Comment: Please add the [tag:burninate-request] tag to this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no longer a [plant](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plant) tag. I edited it out from all the questions it was on, and it has since disappeared. See [Do we need to specify what identification is being requested using tags?](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/559/do-we-need-to-specify-what-identification-is-being-requested-using-tags)

It wasn't really a very useful tag anyway.

Answer (score 4):

As you stated, a very high percentage of questions could be tagged with plant. The tag is far too general to be useful and should be burninated. Perhaps even blacklisted.

As it is, practically all of the 18 questions are [identification](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) questions. A number of these questions are also closed.

If the tag is unavailable new users will simply not be able to use the tag, which is a *good* thing. I recommend cleaning up the 18 [plant](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plant) questions.

Comment: I agree with burninating the [tag:plant] tag. Also see http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/559/do-we-need-to-specify-what-identification-is-being-requested-using-tags

Comment: 17 questions now. :) I'd be happy to approve any suggested edits that remove this tag **and** fix anything else that needs fixing in the post (assuming there is anything), including replacing gigantic photos with more appropriately sized ones (like I did [here](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/8448/26) -- see http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/a/254/26 for more about image sizes). Voting or flagging to close can be a viable action too...

Comment: I'll work on it.

Answer (score 2):

It's usually used by newer users in identification questions, to clarify what's being identified. New users also don't necessarily know how to properly use tags, so they often use it where a more specific tag would do (they don't know to be as specific as possible).  In the [Help Center](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it is posted that the identification scope covers diseases and pests, as well as plants:

> - identification, diagnosis or management of plant diseases, pests, or weeds

So if you aren't sure of anything specific (like if it's a [trees](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trees), [shrubs](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shrubs), [perennials](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perennials), [flowers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flowers) question, etc.), this tag would specify that the identification question posted is asking about plants, rather than diseases or pests.

Now, once the question has an answer, it *could* be retagged, and the [plant](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plant) tag could be replaced by something more specific.

Comment: So it's used in conjunction with the identification tag, otherwise it should be switched out for more specific tags?

Comment: @MattS. That's my understanding. Now There are quite a few messily tagged questions on GL, so I haven't been working on them too much (don't want to push all the new stuff down), but I try to retag the new questions as they come out, as well as specify the titles.

Comment: That sounds like a lot of extra work for regular members that shouldn't really be needed.

Comment: @MattS. It isn't really necessary, I'm just picky, and the huge majority of new feed is from new users with no prior tagging experience. And you do get a badge for 500 edits (only three on this site have it).