# Is the tag [Plant-Care] too meta?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently there's a tag [plant-care](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plant-care) with 105 questions using it.

It doesn't look like it's been used anytime recently, and the tag wiki describes itself as:

> General tag for questions on plant care
>
> Use this tag for general questions on plant care. This is an extremely general tag and should be avoided if possible. In most cases there are much more appropriate, specific tags available. E.g. for watering, light, pollination.

It seems to me like it's acting as a catch-all tag for when people weren't sure which tag to use. Similar to the [plant tag](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/557/what-is-the-plant-tag-used-for).

Is this tag too meta? If people are supposed to avoid using it, then why even have it? Or maybe could we come up with a better tag wiki for it to define how it should be used better?