# Please blacklist the [plant] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, blacklist-request

Almost three years ago, we had a question [What is the plant tag used for?](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/557/what-is-the-plant-tag-used-for) with a couple of answers saying [plant](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plant) isn't useful because it's too general — it can apply to every question on the site **except** those that aren't about plants — and should go away. At that time it was edited out of all questions that used it.

Since then, it was reintroduced and proliferated to over 30 questions (including a handful today). I've since edited it out of those questions, and would now like it blacklisted to prevent it from coming back.

As of March 15, 2019 there were a further 14 questions with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is done!

Also blacklisted [plants](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plants) to prevent that from being the go-to replacement option.

Thanks Shog!